# windows service in c# microsoft graph api getAsync() call for users goes in hung state

Tags: c#, async-await, microsoft-graph-api, windows-services

I am reading different mailboxes in windows service using MS graph api using threads. Service runs well for few days, but after it goes in hung state.

By observing logs found that stuck point is while calling `GetAsync()` method for **users**, after that it is not updating log file also but service is showing in running state.

After restarting the service it runs normally for few days.

```
public static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            Task t1 = ParallelThreadOne.MainAsync();
            Task t2 = ParallelThreadSecond.MainAsync();
            Task t3 = ParallelThreadThird.MainAsync();            
            
            await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);

        }

 public static async Task MainAsync()
        {

            try
            {                
                EmailMaster objEmailMaster = new EmailMaster();

                List<MailBoxConfiguration> lstMailBoxConfiguration = objEmailMaster.GetMailBoxInformation(1,logger);
                if (lstMailBoxConfiguration != null)
                {
                    if (lstMailBoxConfiguration.Count != 0)
                    {                        
                        GraphServiceClient client = GetAuthenticatedClient();
                       
                        if (client != null)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < lstMailBoxConfiguration.Count; j++)
                            {                                
                                var users = await graphClient
                                .Users
                                .Request()
                                .Filter("startswith(Mail,'" + lstMailBoxConfiguration[j].EmailId + "')")
                                .GetAsync();                               
                                
                                if (users.Count > 0)
                                {                                   
                                    var msgs = await graphClient
                                           .Users[users[0].Id]
                                           .MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages
                                           .Request().Top(500)
                                           .GetAsync();
                                     
                                        if (msgs.Count > 0)
                                        {
                                            foreach (var item in msgs)
                                            {                                                
                                                //business logic goes here                                                
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            logger.Info("msg.Count is zero");
                                        }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    logger.Info("users.Count is zero");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logger.Info("client is null");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logger.Info("lstMailBoxConfiguration.Count is zero from the database");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Info("lstMailBoxConfiguration is null from the database");
                }
                logger.Info("MainAsync(1) : End of MainAsync(1)");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error("MainAsync(1) : Exception : " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
        public static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
        {
            
            string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureClientId"];
            string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];           
            string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"];
            string getTokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";           
            const string grantType = "client_credentials";
            const string myScopes = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"; 
            string postBody = $"client_id={clientId}&scope={myScopes}&client_secret={password}&grant_type={grantType}";
            try
            {                             
                if (graphClient == null)
                {
                    graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(

                      "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
                        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                            async (requestMessage) =>
                            {                         
                            HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, getTokenUrl);
                                httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                         
                                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
                            string responseBody = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                userToken = JObject.Parse(responseBody).GetValue("access_token").ToString();
                                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", userToken);
                            }));
                }
                return graphClient;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error("Could not create a graph client: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                logger.Info("GetAuthenticatedClient() :inside finally!");   
            }

            return graphClient;
        }
```

Comment: From [Create a Microsoft Graph client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=CS): *You can use a single client instance for the lifetime of the application*.  This is a strong indication that connections remain open. It explains the behavior that the service hangs after a few days.

Answer (score 0):

From looking through the source code of the `GraphServiceClient`, it is using `HTTPClient` as its underlying communication provider.  The `HTTPClient` has an issue because windows keeps TCP/IP connections open for a certain amount of time after the `HTTPClient` is disposed.  If you call `new` and then `dispose` on the `HTTPClient` class fast enough for long enough it can lead to socket starvation. (note, `using(var client = new HTTPClient())` calls `dispose` under the covers when the instance goes out of scope)

Take a look at this blog post on the issue.
https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

You should be able to use a single instance of the `GraphServiceClient` as long as you are talking to the same GraphQL endpoint and fix your issues with the service hanging.  If you add logging you will probably notice that the service hangs after a flurry of activity causing lots of new instances of the `GraphServiceClient` to be created then disposed in a short time frame and your open network connections on the server exploding causing an error that crashes one of your threads.

Comment: Thanks @RubberChickenLeader for your feedback! Do I need to make GetAuthenticatedClient() as async or only static will work?

Comment: @MANOJACHAREKAR async / await code is like a virus.  once you insert it into one spot in the stack, tends to bubble its way up the stack.  Sync to Async code is a pretty large topic that needs its own research with your own code base and cant really be answered from this question for your specific code base.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, using only one instance of GraphServiceClient for the entire application. but same problem persists. service is going in hung state after 2-3 days

Comment: @MANOJACHAREKAR then its probably not the source of your problem.  Sometimes we can get an idea that turns out to be wrong when debugging a hard to diagnose problem.  Next thing would be to watch the processes memory consumption and see if there is a memory leak somewhere.