# Window Service goes in hung state after some days of running when connecting to more than 30 mailboxes using Graph Api

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, windows-services

we are connecting 30+ mailboxes using msgraph api but services hangs after 2-3 days of running.
the main culprit is GetAsync() method for **users**. below is the code for ParallelThreadOne.
similar code is for other threads also.

```
public static async Task MainAsync()
{
    Task t1 = ParallelThreadOne.MainAsync();
    Task t2 = ParallelThreadSecond.MainAsync();
    Task t3 = ParallelThreadThird.MainAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);

}

public static async Task MainAsync()
{

    try
    {
        EmailMaster objEmailMaster = new EmailMaster();

        List<MailBoxConfiguration> lstMailBoxConfiguration = objEmailMaster.GetMailBoxInformation(1, logger);
        if (lstMailBoxConfiguration != null)
        {
            if (lstMailBoxConfiguration.Count != 0)
            {
                Global.client = await Global.GetAuthenticatedClient();

                if (client != null)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < lstMailBoxConfiguration.Count; j++)
                    {
                        var users = await Global.client
                        .Users
                        .Request()
                        .Filter("startswith(Mail,'" + lstMailBoxConfiguration[j].EmailId + "')")
                        .GetAsync();

                        if (users.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var msgs = await Global.client
                                   .Users[users[0].Id]
                                   .MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages
                                   .Request().Top(500)
                                   .GetAsync();

                            if (msgs.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in msgs)
                                {
                                    //business logic goes here                                                
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                logger.Info("msg.Count is zero");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logger.Info("users.Count is zero");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Info("client is null");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Info("lstMailBoxConfiguration.Count is zero from the database");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Info("lstMailBoxConfiguration is null from the database");
        }
        logger.Info("MainAsync(1) : End of MainAsync(1)");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error("MainAsync(1) : Exception : " + ex.Message);
    }

}



public static class Global
{

    public static GraphServiceClient graphClient = null;
    public static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureClientId"];
    public static string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"];
    public static string grantType = "client_credentials";
    public static string getTokenUrl = $"https_://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    public const string myScopes = "https_://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
    public static string postBody = $"client_id={clientId}&scope={myScopes}&client_secret={password}&grant_type={grantType}";
    private static string userToken;


    public static Task<GraphServiceClient> GetAuthenticatedClient(NLog.Logger logger)
    {


        if (graphClient == null)
        {

            try
            {


                graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(

                  "https_://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
                    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                        async (requestMessage) =>
                        {

                            HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, getTokenUrl);
                            httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

                            string responseBody = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            userToken = JObject.Parse(responseBody).GetValue("access_token").ToString();
                            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", userToken);
                        }));

                return Task.FromResult(graphClient);
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
            {
                logger.Error("GetAuthenticatedClient_Out of memory Exception:  " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error("Could not create a graph client: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult(graphClient);
    }
```

we are using dll version microsoft.graph(3.20.0) & microsoft.graph.core(1.22.0) and application is window service(C#) and framework is 4.6.1

Comment: When you see the hang what graph error response you get... share the requestid, timestamp & the detailed error.

Comment: @dev :Below is the code where service is going in hung state.We analysed this by applying logs before and after this line of code.
      there is no response after calling this code.
 var users = await Global.client 
                                .Users
                                .Request()
                                .Filter("startswith(Mail,'" + lstMailBoxConfiguration[j].EmailId + "')")
                                .GetAsync();

Answer (score 0):

Create a MS Graph Client, as in below link, can be used as a single client instance for the lifetime of the application.

This is a strong indication that connections remain open. It explains the behavior that the service hangs after a few days

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=CS

Reference SO Thread: [windows service in c# microsoft graph api getAsync() call for users goes in hung state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68803892/windows-service-in-c-sharp-microsoft-graph-api-getasync-call-for-users-goes-in)

Comment: We  are creating only single instance of MsGraphClient as I have already attached code of in my post. i have created static class Global for the same.